# What kind of philosophy is non-dual philosophy?

Tags: metaphysics

I have come across non-dual philosophy online. Was wondering what exactly it is.

Comment: _Where_ online? And did you try the dictionary, wikipedia, google, the context, ...?

Comment: first try to understand what is meant by dualism and then what is non-dual becomes more obvious at least to explicate.

Comment: Your question lacks information that we need to answer appropriately. If you know philosophical vocabulary and have some insights, start with the [Stanford entry on dualism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dualism/) and work your way from there. If not, start with Wikipedia [on Dualism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dualism) and [Nondualism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dualism), a thing you should have done before posing your question.

Answer (score 3):

Non-dual refers to non-dualistic philosophies. Among them are the Advaita Vedanta of Hinduism, Buddhism, and Sankhya Yoga. A good intro that talks about non-duality in different philosophies is "Non-Duality: A Study In Comparative Philosophy" by David Loy. Humanities Press, 1988.

Answer (score 0):

Non Dualism is found in both western and Indan philisophical systems. Non Dualism is essentially monoism. But if ultimate reality is addressed as being one that is monoistic, them it amounts to attributing qualities to the ultimate reality. But we also know that describibg smthing by way of attributing qualities goes against perefect nature of ultimate reality. It makes the ultimate reality imperfect. Thus non dualist term monoism as non dualism. It simply means double negation. In simple words it means '' not two'' This means ''one'' 
In Indian philosophy, a major school of Non Dualism is Advait Vedanta. Shankaracharya was the leading propounder of this school. Advaita is Sanskrit translation of Non Dualism. 
Similar non dualistic notions are also found in western philisophiical schools as well
For ex: Berkely says '' aLL  IS GOD AND GOD IS ALL''

Simply put, non dualism in metaphysical sense means that ''there are not 2 ultimate realities'' 
Contrary to non dualism is dualism and pluralism. 
For ex. Samkhya School of Indian Philosophy is a major dualistic school. Here Prakriti and Purush are the 2 ultimate realities.

Pluralims means that there are many ultimate realities.
For ex. Nyaya Vaisehikas of Indian Philosophy are pluralitic metaphysically.